# Swiftで参照されるクラスの定義情報のありかについて

Tags: swift, xcode

xcodeを使い、swiftでコードを書く際
command+クラス名クリックで、クラス定義の情報など参照できると思いますが
あの定義ファイルはどこにあるのでしょう？
(Objective-Cのヘッダファイルは探せば見つかるのですが、肝心のswiftの方は見つからず。。）

意図としては、クラスや関数の用途を簡単に確認したい場合
ドキュメントを見るより、定義ファイルが直接見れたら楽かなと思った次第です。

Answer (score 1):

> (Objective-Cのヘッダファイルは探せば見つかるのですが、肝心のswiftの方は見つからず。。）

swiftからはObjective-Cのクラスをそのまま使うことができるので、定義ファイルは共通です。

クラス定義の情報はObjective-Cのヘッダーを参照しているということになります。

[Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C: Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考に貼って頂いた情報も読ませて頂こうと思います。

つまり、swiftからUIViewController等の定義情報を参照する場合
swiftで書かれた定義情報が参照できると思うのですが、あの内容はObjective-Cで書かれた定義ファイルをxcodeで変換して見せているだけということですね。

直接見る場合は、あの形式で見れないとなると残念です。